# IONIC facebook integration not pass on review

Tags: facebook, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app, ngcordova

I use IONIC framework to build my app and it's work really great.

I use ngCordova for facebook integration, so I have to set facebook app to be a "web".

When I send request for app review because I want to use "publish_action" permission they not approve my app and comment like this.

```
"if your app is an android app, you will need to apply for that platform instead of the web platform, as I can't review an android app in a web platform submission"
```

Is there anyway to setup my facebook app as Android?

Or How can I help my request to pass their review?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the review for android.
Which means going to the google developer, creating a project, uploading an apk (a fake one, not important), then you get your android ID (no need to publish), you then register your app for android on facebook developer (with android ID) and you upload your real apk for the android review with a videocast of how it works.